# UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor does not work in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, uiappearance

I ported a file from Objective_c to Swift that among its configurations changed the tabbar color: the code I used in objective-c was:

```
UIColor* barColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:.88 green:.05 blue:.05 alpha:1];
if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)])
{
    // iOS7
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor;
}
else
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:barColor];
    // older
    //self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = barColor;
}
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
```

and the corresponding code in Swift is:

```
let barColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.05, blue:0.05, alpha:1)
if UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.compare("8.0", options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedDescending
    {
        // iOS8+
     UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor=barColor
     //UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent=false
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor;
    }
```

Yet, while the objective-c code did change the tab-bar color, the corresponding swift code leave it unscathed, at least on the simulator. What I did wrong?

Comment: What is even more puzzling is that I have a sister ViewController in which I use:
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor; even on iOS 9 without any crash and changing the color of the tabbar.
If I use that piece of code in the original viewcontroller  on iOS 9 I have a crash instead, and the alternative code does not have effects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was due to the navigationBar not being initialized at ViewWillAppear time possibly for a IOS 9 bug. I solved the issue by optionally accessing it as in:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor;
```

This code is fine from iOS7+ and so no condition is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The appearance settings should applied at the time of application launch.
So it is better to set:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = barColor
```

In

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor=barColor
  return true
}
```